# Postgres find rows with min/max value in column

Tags: postgresql

I got huge `event` table with `modified` date column. And I need to find first and latest event. Queries looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE modified = (SELECT MAX(modified) FROM event);
SELECT * FROM event WHERE modified = (SELECT MIN(modified) FROM event);
```

I want to speed up this queries. B-tree index on `modified` could help, but it's not looks like best solution. Even index scan requires O(logn) operations and index itself requires a lot of space, while to store only min and max values constant space is enough.

Is there a way to execute such queries in constant time? Or at lest in O(logn) time with constant space overhead?

Comment: If you have the scope to do this, you could consider adding a trigger to whatever view is on top of this table to automatically store whatever `modified` data is written in another table which holds just the min and max modified values. Assuming the newly written is always larger, you'd just update a row in that new table with the new value (or conditionally, if it's not always larger). Min would presumably always be the same, else you would also conditionally update that field. You end up being able to access those two values very quickly.

Comment: Seems like a deeply impractical concern.  The overhead of juggling snapshots is going to swamp the cost of descending through the logN levels of a Btree index when the path through is already in shared_buffers.  Just how huge is this table?  Can your disk array be seen from space?  Does it have an entire nuclear plant dedicated to powering it?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have an index on `modified` then this might be faster:

```
select *
from event
order by modified
limit 1
union all 
select *
from event
order by modified desc
limit 1
```

---

> Even index scan requires O(logn) operations

Not if the requirement is to find the highest or lowest value. That is essentially O(1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have estimates which surely include the min and max, but surely exclude the vast majority of the table, you could use a partial index fence-posted by them.  For example here, I know that at least one value is outside the range at each end:

```
create index on pgbench_accounts (abalance ) where abalance <10 or abalance >999990;
```

You need to add a spurious WHERE clause to get the index to be used.

```
select min(abalance) from pgbench_accounts where abalance<10;
```

I can't measure a difference in performance between the partial index and the full index, but the difference in size is hard to miss (32 MB vs 16 kB for a table with 2 million rows)